# Selenium Web hook NoSuchElementError (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, twitter

I am experimenting with Selenium for Node.js, and have encountered a small problem. I have been trying to navigate the Twitter log in page, specifically finding the username and password log in boxes and sending the required keys.

**Code Snippet:**

```
let element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@class="sign-in btn btn-primary"]')).click();
let login = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@name="session[username_or_email]"]'))
login.sendKeys("username");
```

**HTML Snippet:**. (https://twitter.com/login)

```
<input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" name="session[username_or_email]" 
spellcheck="false" type="text" dir="auto" data-focusable="true" 
class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l 
r-1inuy60 r-utggzx r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-1lrr6ok r-1dz5y72 r-1ttztb7 r-13qz1uu" value="">
```

However, I am receiving the **error**: `NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@name="session[username_or_email]"]"}`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
I've tried waiting for the page to load using this:

```
driver.wait(function () {
      return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name ='session[username_or_email]']"));
  }, 10000);
```

However I am still receiving the error that 'session[username_or_email]' can not be found

Comment: Provide some wait before interacting username element.

Comment: How can I do that in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Check the element is present inside any `iframe` ?Check your DOM tree upwards your input element?

Comment: I haven't been able to detect any Iframes, so it may be a different problem

Comment: Since this is login page can you share your url for diagnose?

Comment: https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=https%3A%2F%2Fanalytics.twitter.com%2Fabout&hide_message=1

Thanks for your help! @KunduK

Comment: Yes you must have some other problem i have verified with python code and xpath is absolutely fine.Its working with my python code.

Comment: Just curious to know where did you get sign-in button.I can see `Log In` link Not  any `sign-in` button

Comment: I haven't even got that far! I just wanted to find the initial username box, and use sendkeys for my username.. Maybe I should use python instead of javascript